# MediaWiki - What files render the html?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to add a PHP function directly into the "homepage" and not via the edit.

Windows Search is fubar so I'm asking what .php file i am to edit to be able to insert my own code into.

Comment: Huh? You can add code to any PHP file. *What do you want to achieve?* If you told us that, we might lead you to the right files.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where on the page you want the content to show up...

If you are just trying to print out debugging information, you can put print or echo statements at the end of your LocalSettings.php file and it will be added to the top of all pages in the wiki.

If you want to put content into a specific spot in a specific page, you probably want to [write an extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aExtensions) that uses one of the [page rendering hooks](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks#Hooks_grouped_by_function) like [ArticleViewHeader](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ArticleViewHeader).

If you can refine your question to be a bit more specific about what type of content you want to add and where you want to add it, I could give you a better recommendation for a specific hook to use.